# if i close the dialog box, a NullPointerException occurs. how do i get rid of it?

Tags: java, exception

I am currently making a quiz program but if i close the dialog box when it is asking for an input, a NullPointerException occurs. How do i make it do something else, like display a text message and prompt for a valid entry.

```
String qn_1_ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null,
            "What is the answer for Question 1? \nPink \nBlue \nBlack \nRed",
            JOptionPane.OK_OPTION
    );

if (qn_1_ans.equals(qn_1_right_ans)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Thats correct");
        Score = Score + 1;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is " +     qn_1_right_ans);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-)

> **Returns:**
>  user's input, **or null meaning the user canceled the input**

*Emphasis added*